# How to search a list and return the specific strings and data associated with it using Java

Tags: java, string, list, methods

I have a list of names with Account numbers associated with them. How would I create a method that when I type a certain name from the keyboard it would search the list and return all the account numbers associated with it using java? For example if I pass the name "Lisheen" to the method it would return all the account numbers associated with it along with the other account name and numbers that starts with "Lisheen".

```
      Name                     Account Number
     A-Wear                      78090231
     John                        76581234
     PSTN                        76811467
     Arni Harald                 78062351
     Barry Moore                 77002345
     Chill industries            79205416
     Espion                      78348903
     Michael                     78583451
     Kathleen O'Hara             78505421
     Liam Home                   76314321
     Lisheen Mine                78074315
     Lisheen Mine                78085413
     Lisheen Mine                78083413
     Lisheen Mine                78083413
     Lisheen Mine                78084315
     Lisheen Mine                78086441
     Lisheen Mine Res. RD        77972341
     Lisheen Mine Res. SW        77662345
     Lisheen Mine Res. TMcK      78521234
     Nolan Supermarket           79101234
     Nolan Transport             78095413
     PR Reilly Merchants Quay    77387689
     PR Reilly Togher            77382351
     PR Reilly Howth             77383215
     SightSavers                 78228794
```

Comment: What does your list look like (implementation)? And what have you tried?

Comment: What does your list look like?

Comment: a simple list of what you have to do is : read the data e.g. from a file, parse the text and transform into simple objets, read the user input e.g from the console, find the object in the list using the specified criteria. What have you tried? do you have any specific question?

Comment: is these are Collection list?

Comment: You ahve not provided any code.

Comment: Its better using `Map` to do this.

Comment: That is the list above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> getSortedHashMapForEmployees(string searchKeyword,List<yourDtoFromDB> orginalListFromDB)
    {
        HashMap<String, List<String>>hashmap=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (List<yourDtoFromDB> orginalList : orginalListFromDB) 
        {
            if(orginalList.getName().contains(searchKeyword))
            {
                List<String>accountNo=new ArrayList<String>();
                if(hashmap.containsKey(orginalList.getName()))
                {
                    accountNo=hashmap.get(orginalList.getName());
                }
                accountNo.add(orginalList.getAccountNo());
                hashmap.put(orginalList.getName(), accountNo);
            }
        }
        return hashmap;

    }
```

Comment: but i also want to return the account numbers associated with it

Comment: @Lance check my answer it will reply your question

Comment: its just a list of names and account numbers and yes same user can have different account numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map<String, List<Integer>>` for this purpose.

First process your list and add them into the `Map` (Assuming `Element` to be your custom class containing `fullAccountName` and `accountNumber`)

```
for(Element e : list) {
   List<Integer> accNums = map.get(e.getName());   
   if(accNums == null) {
         accNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         map.put(e.getName(), accNums);
   }
   accNums.add(e.getAccountNumber());
}
```

Once processed,

```
for(Entry<String, List<Integer>> e : map.entrySet()){
   if(e.getKey().startsWith(userSearch)) {
      return e; // which is essentially the key value pair of acc name vs. all acc. numbers
   }
}
```

Comment: you forget to add the new `ArrayList` to the map (and misspelled `accNums`)

Comment: I would suggest to use contains instead of startsWith as it will be more better search.

Comment: any easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a map to do this as you need to associate the name with the account numbers.

You can use `Map<String, List<Integer>>` for every name store a corresponding list of account numbers.(Try doing this by yourself)

Then for finding the search key use a method and pass the map and the search key. Then you can use the below Pseudo-code to search your key.

This is the sample Pseudo-code:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> temp=new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
for(Entry<String, List<Integer>> e : map.entrySet()){
   if(e.getKey().contains(searchKey)) {
     temp.put(e.getKey(),e.getValue());
   }
}
return temp;
```

Here temp will be a map containing the names along with account numbers that match the search key.